# setBackButtonBackgroundImage: results in button displaying strangely

Tags: ios

I'm calling the following code to place my own back button into the navigation bar

```
  [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setBackButtonBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_back_static"]  forState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

But the result comes out like this:

[image]

I tried experimenting a bit with resizing such as

```
resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 13, 0, 5)];
```

but still a similar result:

[image]

This is what the button I'm trying to add looks like:

[image]

Its a .png 101 pixels by 60 pixels (I don't know why that uneven dimension, that is how the designer gave it to me).

Why does it not appear properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image is twice the height it should be, so you're only seeing the top half.

Perhaps this is the @2x version of the image that you have and you've not named it correctly?

If not, you need an image that's half the height / width.